# overlapping of label and value on input text box in materialize in ember

Tags: ember.js, materialize

i have installed materialize plugin in my ember app using 'bower install materialize'

i have created a form in my hbs--

```
> <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l8">
>               <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
>               {{input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="validate" value="overlap"}}
>               <label for="email">Email<i class="mandatoryIcon">*</i></label>
>             </div>
```

but in ui this label and value are getting overlapped. need to fix this issue..
how to do ????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the input already has a value, you need to initialize it that way.

Go look at the [documentation](http://materializecss.com/forms.html). (*Look for prefilling text fields*)

In javascript, do the following:

```
Materialize.updateTextFields();
```

Or add the class `active` to the label.

**Update:** based on the new [documentation](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html) the following code is correct :

```
M.updateTextFields();
```

Comment: this is correct but i want to initialize this with onclick function.how to handle this in ember??

Answer (score 6):

Add `class="active"` for the label field, Issue will be solved.

```
<label for="email" class="active" >Email<i class="mandatoryIcon">*</i>
```